# View new warnings for this build in Warning Next Generation Plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

[Warnings Next Generation plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#remote-api) contains very useful graphs showing new warnings in this build

Anyone know how to see which warnings make up the new warnings? I can't figure it out via the UI and docs.  I have the source and that'll be my next step of no one knows.  There's an API too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above the table we see two charts.  If we click on the arrow for the donut chart we can view the `Reference Comparison` and if we click on the part of the donut pertaining to the items for which we care, then the table changes what it displays.

In this case, I care about `New` items so I click on the tiny sliver at 12 o'clock on the donut and see just that one new item.

[image]

This is either a brilliant design or a horrible one.  A coworker figured it out.  I didn't see it even after looking through the code.